# How can I iterate through all my checked checkboxes?

Tags: jquery

My site has the following:

```
<td><input id="inp_0001010030" type="checkbox"></td>
<td><input id="inp_0001010031" type="checkbox"></td>
<td><input id="inp_0001010032" type="checkbox"></td>
<td><input id="inp_0001010033" type="checkbox"></td>
<td><input id="inp_0001010034" type="checkbox"></td>
```

These are created dynamically.

And a form that's at the bottom of the page outside of the area with the above rows:

```
<form action="??" method="??" >
   <input value="Action"  type="submit">
      <select id="SelectedAction" >
        <option value="1">Delete</option>
        <option value="2">Move</option>
      </select>
</form>
```

After the rows have been created I need to have the clicked event the form button go look at each checkbox and then call a javascript function with the id and the value of SelectedAnswer for each checkbox that it finds checked.

Note that if there is a way to do this without the form then it's even better. I just don't know enough about jQuery.

Is this the kind of thing I can do easily with jQuery?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery select (each) all checked checkboxes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083881/jquery-select-each-all-checked-checkboxes)

Comment: *I just don't know enough about jQuery*: Time to learn more ;) http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
$("input[type=submit]").click(function () {
    var answer = $("#SelectedAnswer").val();
    $("input:checked").each(function () {
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        alert("Do something for: " + id + ", " + answer);
    });
});
```

Comment: How about if I take the button out of the form? Is there really any need for me to have a form there?

Comment: No. The form has no purpose unless you're going to use it to send data to the server.

Answer (score 14):

```
$('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function() {
    // Do something interesting
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to add a class to your checkboxes. After that, use jQuery's `.each()` method like this:

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" class="list">
<input type="checkbox" class="list">
<input type="checkbox" class="list">
<input type="checkbox" class="list">
<input type="checkbox" class="list">
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("form input[type='submit']").click(function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();

        // This gets the value of the currently selected option
        var value = $(this).children(":selected").val();

        $(".list").each(function()
        {
            if($(this).is(':checked'))
            {
                $(this).fadeOut();
                // Do stuff with checked box
            }
            else
            {
                // Checkbox isn't checked
            }
        })
    });
});
```

**EDIT**

Please see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jtnue/1/) (code above). I've only implemented the delete option (not very well), but use the `value` variable to check which option is being selected. If you want this to happen before the form is submitted, remove the `e.preventDefault()` line.

Comment: Is there some way that I can fire this "checking" by clicking on my input button that is in the form. Do I still need a form as I need to get the value of the select list?

Comment: I like this method because you can be very specific with which checkboxes you want to look at without having to encapsulate them inside some container like a form.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely.

The first thing you want to do is bind an event handler to your submit event on the form using the `$.submit()` handler. Next you'll want to iterate over each of the checked input elements:

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    var action = $('#SelectedAction option:selected', this).val();
    $('table input:checkbox:checked').each(function(i){
       return doMyCustomFunction(this, action);
    });
}
```

Your custom function ("`doMyCustomFunction()`" in my example) should return either true or false depending on whether you wanted to submit your form or not.

By way of a practical example, it might look something like this:

```
function doMyCustomFunction(el, formAction) {
   console.info('The element ID is ' + el.id + ' and the action is ' + formAction);
   return true;
}
```